# Effect of a Lie group morphism associated to a Lie algebra morphism to wedge product

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I currently struggeling with the last exercise on my assignment:

Fix $\omega\in\bigwedge^3(\mathbb R^n)^*$. Let $G$ be a Lie group, $\rho\colon G\to GL(n,\mathbb R)$ a Lie group morphism such that
$$
\omega(\rho(g)w_1, \rho(g)w_2, \rho(g)w_3) = \omega(w_1,w_2,w_3)
$$
for all $g\in G$ and $w_i\in\mathbb R^n$. Now we take the associated Lie algebra morphism $R = (\rho)_{*e} \colon \mathfrak{g}\to Mat(n,\mathbb R)$.

> Show that
>   $$
> \omega(R(v)w_1,w_2,w_3)+\omega(w_1,R(v)w_2,w_3)+\omega(w_1,w_2,R(v)w_3) = 0
> $$
>   for all $v\in\mathfrak g$ and $w_i\in\mathbb R^n$.

---

It looks to me like somehow differentiating the first equation and ending up with the second but to apply the exterior derivative of a k-form we need another representation.
Another thought was using the relation
$$
\omega(\rho(g)w_1, \rho(g)w_2, \rho(g)w_3) = \det(\rho(g))\omega(w_1,w_2,w_3)
$$
thus we see that $\det(\rho(g))=1$ by the first equation and we get $R(v)$ has trace zero.

Any help would be very much appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $v\in\mathfrak g$ and $t\in\mathbb R$, then$$\omega\bigl(\rho(e^{tv})w_1,\rho(e^{tv})w_2,\rho(e^{tv})w_3\bigr)=\omega(w_1,w_2,w_3).$$Differentiating both sides at $t=0$, you get$$\omega\bigl(R(v)w_1,w_2,w_3\bigr)+\omega\bigl(w_1,R(v)w_2,w_3\bigr)+\omega\bigl(w_1,w_2,R(v)w_3\bigr)=0.$$

Comment: This already helped a lot, thanks! But I have two little questions:

For your first equation there has to be a $v\in\mathfrak g$ for every $g\in G$ such that
$$
\rho(g) = R(e^{tv}).
$$
I could see why there exist a matrix $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ for every $B\in GL(n,\mathbb R)$ such that $B=e^{A}$ but why does it still hold for the morphisms?

For the differentiation I need
$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}|_{t=0} R(\mathrm e^{tv}) = 
R(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}|_{t=0} \mathrm e^{tv}).
$$
I think there was a property which said that morphisms and the differentiation commute?

Comment: Concerning your first question, all that I need (and all that I used) was that$$(\forall v\in\mathfrak{g})(\forall t\in\mathbb{R}):e^{iv}\in G.$$Now use the fact that$$\left.\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\right|_{t=0}e^{tv}=v$$together with the chain rule.

Comment: I think my main problem was the $e^{tv}$-notion because I have just a theorem which says that there exists a curve with the same properties but everything works now. Thank you very much! :-)

Comment: Unless you think that I am asking too much, perhaps that you could upvote my answer.

Comment: Hehe, I already did but apparently I don't have enough reputation for it to take effect. But it said as soon as I have enough the well-earned upvote will be counted. :-)

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: if $e^{tv} \in G$, how can you apply the Lie algebra morphism $R$ to it then?

Comment: When I wrote $R(e^{tv})w_i$, what I meant was $\rho(e^{tv})w_i$. I'v edited my answer.